# How to use nested if statements within a pandas dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, finance

I have a dataframe that consists of the U.S. unemployment rate, a year long moving average for the unemployment rate, a monthly price of the S&P 500 along with a 10 month moving average.

```
start = "1950-01-01"
end = "2017-12-31"

fred_unemployment = quandl.get("FRED/UNRATE", start_date=start, end_date=end)
fred_unemployment["UE 12MMA"] = fred_unemployment["Value"].rolling(12).mean()
fred_unemployment["SPY"] = spy["Adj Close"]
fred_unemployment["SPY 200d MA"] = spy["Adj Close"].rolling(10).mean()
```

From this I'm looking to identify the rows where:
fred_unemployment["Value"] > fred_unemployment["UE 12MMA"]

Then have it check if fred_unemployment["SPY"] < fred_unemployment["SPY 200d MA"]

Ideally this would result in certain buy and sell decisions by using what I believe are called "nested if statements" ie:

```
if this:
    if that:
        Sell Stock
    else:
        Buy Stock
else:
    Buy Stock
```

Here's where I'm stuck. I've created another column called fred_unemployment["Signals"] and am currently using np.where that sets the "Signal" columns values to either 1 or 0 depending on the conditions.

```
fred_unemployment["Signal"] = np.where((fred_unemployment["Value"] > fred_unemployment["UE 12MMA"]) &
                                   (fred_unemployment["SPY"] < fred_unemployment["SPY 200d MA"]), 0, 1)
```

So while this works in some cases it wouldn't work in the case where the "Values" < "UE 12MMA" and the "SPY" > "SPY 200d MA" because instead of the nested if statements it's using the if and statement.

Here's a few lines from the dataframe

In summary, how can I create the nested if statement result to sort through the pandas dataframe?

Here's the head of the dataframe:

```
            Value  UE 12MMA     SPY  SPY 200d MA  Signal
Date                                                    
1990-01-01    5.4       NaN  359.69      334.658       1
1990-02-01    5.3       NaN  328.79      337.898       1
1990-03-01    5.2       NaN  332.74      340.260       1
1990-04-01    5.4       NaN  338.70      341.933       1
1990-05-01    5.4       NaN  332.25      343.235       1
```

the tail:

```
             Value UE 12MMA   SPY      SPY 200d MA   Signal
Date                                                     
2010-08-01    9.5  9.741667  1125.86     1109.393       1
2010-09-01    9.5  9.716667  1080.29     1113.134       1
2010-10-01    9.4  9.666667  1146.24     1116.872       1
2010-11-01    9.8  9.658333  1184.38     1122.011       1
2010-12-01    9.3  9.608333  1206.07     1133.699       1
```

and a few where you can see the signal as 0.

```
             Value  UE 12MMA  SPY      SPY 200d MA  Signal
Date                                                     
1990-12-01    6.3  5.616667   324.10      335.106       0
1991-01-01    6.4  5.700000   326.45      334.477       0
1991-12-01    7.3  6.850000   381.40      382.923       0
1998-09-01    4.6  4.558333   994.26     1057.417       0
2001-01-01    4.2  3.983333  1283.27     1430.739       0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some example data?

Comment: By example data do you mean show the output from the above line of code or just some of the lines from the dataframe? Happy to provide either, just wanted to make sure I was understanding.

Comment: Some lines from the Dataframe. It would be much easier to reproduce.

Comment: Okay I've edited the post to include a few lines from the datafame :)

Comment: Does column `Signal` in your example show expected result or not?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `np.where()` you can use `df['Signal'].apply(**YourFunction**)`

For example:

```
def signal_(val, ue, spy, spyma):
    if val > ue:
        if spy < spyma:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        return 1

df["Signal"] = df.apply(lambda row: signal(
    row['Value'], row['UE 12MMA'], row['SPY'], row['SPY 200d MA']), axis=1)
```

The same but using `all()` to check if all condition are **True**:

```
def signal(val, ue, spy, spyma):
    condition = all([val > ue, spy < spyma])
    return 0 if condition else 1

df["Signal"] = df.apply(lambda row: signal(
    row['Value'], row['UE 12MMA'], row['SPY'], row['SPY 200d MA']), axis=1)
```

It is not clear from question, which result you expect. Does 'Signal' column show expected result or factual result wich you are not satisfied with?
Anyway, it may be useful to check the documentation about [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) functions.

The full code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Example data emulation
data_string = '''1990-01-01,5.4,NaN,359.69,334.658,1
1990-02-01,5.3,NaN,328.79,337.898,1
1990-03-01,5.2,NaN,332.74,340.260,1
1990-04-01,5.4,NaN,338.70,341.933,1
1990-05-01,5.4,NaN,332.25,343.235,1
2010-08-01,9.5,9.741667,1125.86,1109.393,1
2010-09-01,9.5,9.716667,1080.29,1113.134,1
2010-10-01,9.4,9.666667,1146.24,1116.872,1
2010-11-01,9.8,9.658333,1184.38,1122.011,1
2010-12-01,9.3,9.608333,1206.07,1133.699,1
1990-12-01,6.3,5.616667,324.10,335.106,0
1991-01-01,6.4,5.700000,326.45,334.477,0
1991-12-01,7.3,6.850000,381.40,382.923,0
1998-09-01,4.6,4.558333,994.26,1057.417,0
2001-01-01,4.2,3.983333,1283.27,1430.739,0
2001-01-01,4.2,3.983333,1500.27,1430.739,0'''

columns = ["Date", "Value", "UE 12MMA", "SPY", "SPY 200d MA", "Signal"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [x.split(',') for x in data_string.split('\n')], columns=columns)
print(df, '\n\n----\n')


# Posible solutions:
df["Signal2"] = np.where(
    (df["Value"] > df["UE 12MMA"]) & (df["SPY"] < df["SPY 200d MA"]), 0, 1)


def signal(val, ue, spy, spyma):
    condition = all([val > ue, spy < spyma])
    return 0 if condition else 1


df["Signal3"] = df.apply(lambda row: signal(
    row['Value'], row['UE 12MMA'], row['SPY'], row['SPY 200d MA']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          Date Value  UE 12MMA      SPY SPY 200d MA Signal
0   1990-01-01   5.4       NaN   359.69     334.658      1
1   1990-02-01   5.3       NaN   328.79     337.898      1
2   1990-03-01   5.2       NaN   332.74     340.260      1
3   1990-04-01   5.4       NaN   338.70     341.933      1
4   1990-05-01   5.4       NaN   332.25     343.235      1
5   2010-08-01   9.5  9.741667  1125.86    1109.393      1
6   2010-09-01   9.5  9.716667  1080.29    1113.134      1
7   2010-10-01   9.4  9.666667  1146.24    1116.872      1
8   2010-11-01   9.8  9.658333  1184.38    1122.011      1
9   2010-12-01   9.3  9.608333  1206.07    1133.699      1
10  1990-12-01   6.3  5.616667   324.10     335.106      0
11  1991-01-01   6.4  5.700000   326.45     334.477      0
12  1991-12-01   7.3  6.850000   381.40     382.923      0
13  1998-09-01   4.6  4.558333   994.26    1057.417      0
14  2001-01-01   4.2  3.983333  1283.27    1430.739      0
15  2001-01-01   4.2  3.983333  1500.27    1430.739      0 

----

          Date Value  UE 12MMA      SPY SPY 200d MA Signal  Signal2  Signal3
0   1990-01-01   5.4       NaN   359.69     334.658      1        1        1
1   1990-02-01   5.3       NaN   328.79     337.898      1        1        1
2   1990-03-01   5.2       NaN   332.74     340.260      1        1        1
3   1990-04-01   5.4       NaN   338.70     341.933      1        1        1
4   1990-05-01   5.4       NaN   332.25     343.235      1        1        1
5   2010-08-01   9.5  9.741667  1125.86    1109.393      1        1        1
6   2010-09-01   9.5  9.716667  1080.29    1113.134      1        1        1
7   2010-10-01   9.4  9.666667  1146.24    1116.872      1        1        1
8   2010-11-01   9.8  9.658333  1184.38    1122.011      1        1        1
9   2010-12-01   9.3  9.608333  1206.07    1133.699      1        1        1
10  1990-12-01   6.3  5.616667   324.10     335.106      0        0        0
11  1991-01-01   6.4  5.700000   326.45     334.477      0        0        0
12  1991-12-01   7.3  6.850000   381.40     382.923      0        0        0
13  1998-09-01   4.6  4.558333   994.26    1057.417      0        1        1
14  2001-01-01   4.2  3.983333  1283.27    1430.739      0        0        0
15  2001-01-01   4.2  3.983333  1500.27    1430.739      0        1        1
```

As you can see my function returns the same result as yours, but it is not equal to values of original 'Signal' column. So, what is the right column?
Let me know, if I can help further.